# Set new cell value by cell name in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm new to Java and Apache POI, but I got this task where I have to read from the command line the name of the Excel file and the name and values of the columns that needs to be modified.

So in the end the application will run like this: 
java test -f test.xls -i B2=10;B3=20;B4=30

I have created a map that holds the cell name and their values, but I don't know how to use this map in order to access cells by their name (eg.:  B2) and set the new value (eg.: 10).

My code so far is bellow:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class ReadExcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // Will contain cell name / value pair for input cells and output cells
        Map<String, String> inputCellsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> outputCellsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Open the Excel file
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(args[1]));

        // Get the current workbook
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

        // Get the first sheet of the workbook
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Get the input cells that need to be modified and
        // store their name and value in the inputCellsMap
        for (String element : args[3].split(";")) {
            inputCellsMap.put(element.split("=")[0], element.split("=")[1]);
        }

        // Loop through the cells that need to be modified and 
        // set the new value in the Excel document
        Iterator<Entry<String,String>> iterator = inputCellsMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String,String> entry = (Map.Entry<String,String>) iterator.next();

            // TODO
            // Get cells by name and set their new value

            //System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value :" + entry.getValue());
        }           

        workbook.close();       
    }
}
```

Comment: The first idea that came to me is to set the Map value to Cell instead of String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have the entry, get the cell reference text, e.g. `"B2"`, and the value.

Create a [`CellReference`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html) using the text.  Then you can obtain the 0-based row and column indexes that you can use to get the `Row` and then the `Cell` object, on which you can call [`setCellValue`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue(java.util.Calendar)).

```
CellReference cr = new CellReference(entry.getKey());
int r = cr.getRow();
int c = cr.getCol();

Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
if (row == null)
    row = sheet.createRow(r);
Cell cell = row.getCell(c, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
cell.setCellValue(entry.getValue());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got an error saying that "CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Comment: One more thing. It seems that it sets the value, but when I try to get it later, I can't. I think it should be set as numeric. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Parse the value into an `int` (or another numeric primitive type), then call `Cell`'s overload `setCellValue(int)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can access a row and column using these methods.  (eg. E101)

```
sheet.getRow(100).getCell(5)
```